# When should I use AutoSeededRandomPool (and not NonblockingRng)?

Tags: cryptography, crypto++

I found Crypto++ provides several random generators: `AutoSeededRandomPool`, `AutoSeededX917RNG` and so on. I know some details about these generators and the usage of them, I just wondered when I need them?

`AutoSeededRandomPool` and `AutoSeededX917RNG` default base on `NonblockingRng`, and `NonblockingRng` base on `/dev/urandom`, the `/dev/urandom` base on `/dev/random` and `ChaCha`.

I googled and found many articles said that `/dev/urandom` is secure enough and suit for all(almost?) scenarios, so why use `DES/AES` to encrypt the data read from `/dev/urandom` and much slower than use '/dev/urandom' directly?

When should I use `AutoSeededRandomPool` or `AutoSeededX917RNG`?

Comment: Also see [`RandomNumberGenerator`](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When should I use AutoSeededRandomPool or AutoSeededX917RNG?

You should use `AutoSeededRandomPool`. It uses a PGP-style generator based on AES to extract entropy from the OS pool. It also mixes time with the seed to help harden against VM rollback attacks.

You should also create one `AutoSeededRandomPool` per thread. If you use a single generator for all threads then you need to supply the locks.

`AutoSeededX917RNG` is from a time when NIST approved an AES-based ANSI X9.31 generator for use in FIPS 140 validated cryptography. The X9.17 and X9.31 generators are also used in some other standards, like Automotive and Financial.

NIST deprecated the `AutoSeededX917RNG` generator in 2014 or so in favor of deterministic bit generators specified in [SP800-90](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final).

You can use `AutoSeededX917RNG` if you like. But unless you have requirements to do so then you should just use `AutoSeededRandomPool`.

Comment: "DES, AES, SHA and similar functions are Pseudo Random Functions (PRFs). They extract the entropy from the raw bytes, remove bias, and mostly provide a uniform distribution. " I know this, and as my understanding, that is the reason why can not use /dev/random directly (another reason is /dev/random would block if entropy is not enough). But as I knew, the /dev/urandom has had such a mechanism (maybe not ChaCha20, maybe some other PRFs). Maybe the '/dev/urandom' implementation in some old kernels are not that secure, this is the reason of the AutoSeededRandomPool?

Comment: @alpha - You should use whatever you feel comfortable with. If you don't like `AutoSeededRandomPool` then don't use it. Create your own generator that does what you want. Also see [RandomNumberGenerator | Creating a Generator](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator#Creating_a_Generator).

Comment: I tried AutoSeededRandomPool and NonblockingRng, and found that AutoSeededRandomPool is much slower. I need generator tons of the random finite number (as long as the data) so the speed is important. This post is to make sure that the NonblockingRng does not have security issues. As my understanding, your answer is NonblockingRng does not have security issues, am I right?